# Moshe and filicide

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, parashas-shemos, baby-infant

In Exodus 2:3, baby Moses's mother, unable to further hide him from the authorities, puts him in a box in or near the river. An abandoned baby will soon die. How could / why did she trade in the likelihood that the authorities would find and kill him for her causing his certain death?

Comment: h/t https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48308924#48308924

Comment: In her defense, she also (presumably) posted her daughter there to watch him, and then immediately came back to nurse and raise him an unspecifiedly short time later, when it was safe to do so openly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[R. Avraham Ibn Ezra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra) seems to say that she put him in the river not because that would save him but so that she shouldn't have to witness his death:

> ויוכבד עשתה זאת כי אמרה אל אראה במות הילד

[R. Yosef Ibn Kaspi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Caspi) argues that it is better to choose the possible death than the certain death, and keeping him at home would have led to certain death while placing him in the river allows the possibility of someone saving him:

> ואין לשאול למה עשתה זה כי אין לה עצה טובה ממנה כי הנער בביתה היה המות בצוארו ואין עוד מר ממות כל שכן כי להיותו חוץ מביתה ואין יודע בן מי הוא העלם הנה ההנצל לו מהמות אפשרי לו גם אף על פי שיודע שהוא מילדי העברים כמו שראינו שקרה [כן] ובכלל כי המות הכרחי לו בהיותו בית אמו והוא אפשריי לו בהיותו חוצה וראוי להרחיק בזה ההכרחי ולבחור באפשרי

Similarly, [Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) writes that we learn from this incident that it is important to not give up in a precarious situation, and still attempt to reach a slightly better resolution. To this end Moshe's mother did everything possible to ensure that he would have the possibility of surviving, even if only for a short amount of time more than he would have survived at home:

> התועלת הראשון הוא במידות והוא שאין ראוי לאדם שיתרשל מההשתדלות בהצלה לפי מה שאפשר ואף על פי שיהיה הפגע באופן שיחשוב שלא יתכן שישלם לו ממנו ההצלה הלא תראה כי אם משה כאשר ראתה שלא יכלה עוד להצפין בנה לא נתרשלו ידיה מפני זה מהשתדל בהצלתו לפי מה שאפשר לה ולזה שמה אותו בסוף על שפת היאור תוך התיבה אשר התקינה לו שימלט בה מסכנת הטביעה והתיבה היתה נסתרת תוך הגמי אשר שם  כדי שלא יראה אותה אדם ואף על פי שלא היה יכול להיות שם בזולת מזון הנה לא נמנעה מפני זה מלשית  אותו שם כדי שתרחיק מיתתו זמן מה ואולי תוך הזמן ההוא ימצא לה עזר מהצרה הזאת או תלך בלילה להניקו שם ולזאת הסיבה נתיצבה אחותו מרחוק לדעה מה עשה לו כי אם ימצא  שם אולי תוכל להשיג עם מוצאו בהשתדלותה הטוב שלא יזיק לו

[R. Yaakov Tzvi Mecklenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Tzvi_Mecklenburg%5C) similarly argues that keeping him at home would have led to certain death, while putting him in the river leaves open the possibility of some merciful person saving him:

> כי בהיותו בביתה ימות וודאי ובהוציאה אותו יש אפשר להנצל אולי ימצאהו איש חונן ויחמול עליו

Comment: You excel in finding sources, no doubt! But it all seems begging the question, since we know the result we will justify it anyway.

Comment: Hagar took similar action for a similar reason when fearful that Ishmael would die

Comment: @JJLL Indeed, the last six words of Ibn Ezra are a direct quote of the verse by Hagar.

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Answer (score -5):

1. I don't think we have enough information to estimate the probabilities of either danger - keep the boy or let him float.
2. On the second hand, no strict Halachah is learned by our Rabbis from her behavior (unlike Ralbag's *Drashot* in Alex's answer).
3. Moses was destined to lead the Exodus so his fate was not a subject to his Mother's will. Also, if she chose to leave him at home and he survived, he could not be called Moshe, for he wasn't pulled from the water.

Therefore I conclude, Yocheved acted instinctively and not Halachicly, she didn't even consult her husband(!), with Ruach Hakodesh pushing her to use that way and not another.

*NB: Similarly, we can continue this way of questions - why Batya acted so and so, why Pharao acted so and so etc.*

Comment: Why do you say she didn't consult her husband?